# need c program for 5 minutes timer

Tags: atmega, embedded, programming

i am building a project for a cycling bath in which the motor goes up and down. the micrlimit switch senses up & down position. once switch is activated motor cuts off and timer starts. after 5 minutes the motor starts in reverse direction and moves till it trips the switch theis continues indefinitly. i had written a program as below

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int main(void){
    DDRD=0x00;// for input port-UP & DOWN Micro Switch
    DDRC=0xff;// for output port- UP & DOWN Motor
    while(1){
        if(PIND==0xff)// checking the status of PIN PD5 & PD6, if both is '1', turns ON the down Motor
            _delay_ms(100); // for debouncing of switch
        PORTC=0x40;// turns ON down motor

        if(PIND==0xbf)// checking the status of PIN PD6 (Dn sw), if it is '0', turns off the down Motor
        {
            _delay_ms(100); // for debouncing of switch
            PORTC=0x00;   // Turning off the down Motor
            int32_t second;
            for (second=0; second <5LL*60;++second)
            {
                if (second > 5) 
                {
                    PORTC=0X80; // turn ON UP motor
                } else 
                { PORTC = 0x00;}
            }
            { 
                if(PIND==0xdf);// checking the status of PIN PD5 (UP SW), if it is '0' turns off the UP motor, 
                _delay_ms(100); // For debouncing of switch
                PORTC=0x00;// Turning off the UP Motor
                int32_t second;
                for (second=0; second <5LL*60;++second)
                {
                    if (second > 5) 
                    {
                        PORTC=0X40; // turn ON DOWN motor
                    } else
                    { PORTC = 0x00;}
                }

            }

            { 
                if(PIND==0x9f);// checking the status of PIN PD5 & 6 if both 0 then stop motor
                _delay_ms(100); // for debounicng of switch
                PORTC=0x00; // trun off up/down motor


            }
        }
    }
}
```

pls advise this will work

Comment: I fear the answer but: Why don't you run the program on it's environment and see what happens?

Comment: You need to fix the formatting, particularly the indentation, of your code.

Comment: Probably not, as you've neglected to put any timing delay in the seconds loop.

Comment: sleep(300); //   //

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not get the style award. It might compile, but I will not work as intended.

First you need to define what you want to do. Create a [flowchart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart).

Then you look up how you create a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) in C. Because this looks like a perfect job for a state machine.
Create a small dummy application perhaps, on the pc.

You'll also want to look up how to compare, for set inputs.
`if(PIND==0xdf);` is not the way. Try `if(PIND & (1<<PIN)`.

Then you will have learned a lot, and perhaps your able to run this on target.

*Or, you get a Siemens LOGO (PLC) and program it with an IEC 61131-3 variant.

It will provide you with the building blocks to build this reliably and quickly. At the small cost of the hardware.*

---

To answer your title, to create a wait time this long on an embedded platform a software timer is used. One way to do this is with a system tick.

```
uint32_t stim1 = 0; // unsigned 32 bit software timer 1

const unsigned int interval = 20; // Interval of hardware timer in milliseconds

// Timer 1 Compare interrupt, constant interval, 20 ms for example.
ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{    
    // Saturating increment software timer1
    if(stim1 < (0xFFFFFFFF-interval))
      stim1 += interval;
}

int main(void){
  init_tim1();

  while(1){
    if(stim1 > 1000){      // wait 1 second
      PORTB ^= (1 << 0);   // toggle led
      stim1 = 0;           // reset software timer
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And remove magic numbers like 0xdf